# Ubuntu Mate 17.04 cannot change color scheme

Tags: themes, 17.04, ubuntu-mate

I am running Ubuntu Mate 17.04 and there is no option to change the color scheme (no "Color" tab in the Customize theme dialog). There was this option in previous versions, is there a way to get it back?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no facility to support that feature in GTK3, so it was dropped.

Comment: @Ravexina You blew it reviewing this one. Martin Wimpress is the developer of MATE and he knows what he's talking about. SE's algorithm automatically puts all short answers into the LQ queue for review based on the word count.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color scheme you must

1. Go to your desktop folder
2. Press the right mouse/touchpad button to see the contexual menu
3. Scroll down to folder options
4. Choose global color, (a new window will appear)
5. Press the color button to choose the color that you would like
6. Press apply to change to that color
7. Enjoy your new color scheme.

Comment: What are you taking about ? Post some image because I don't have **folder options** at all